# Ways to print the value of labels in 'compute_loss' of trainer.py in transformers to the terminal during training process

Tags: python, huggingface-trainer

I would like to print the labels to the terminal by adding codes inside `compute loss` of `trainer.py` in transformers.

I tried adding both `print` and `logger.info`, but neither works.

```
def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        """
        How the loss is computed by Trainer. By default, all models return the loss in the first element.

        Subclass and override for custom behavior.
        """
        if self.label_smoother is not None and "labels" in inputs:
            labels = inputs.pop("labels")
        else:
            labels = None
        logger.info(f"{labels}")  # here~!
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        # Save past state if it exists
        # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
        if self.args.past_index >= 0:
            self._past = outputs[self.args.past_index]

        if labels is not None:
            if is_peft_available() and isinstance(model, PeftModel):
                model_name = unwrap_model(model.base_model)._get_name()
            else:
                model_name = unwrap_model(model)._get_name()
            if model_name in MODEL_FOR_CAUSAL_LM_MAPPING_NAMES.values():
                loss = self.label_smoother(outputs, labels, shift_labels=True)
            else:
                loss = self.label_smoother(outputs, labels)
        else:
            if isinstance(outputs, dict) and "loss" not in outputs:
                raise ValueError(
                    "The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: "
                    f"{','.join(outputs.keys())}. For reference, the inputs it received are {','.join(inputs.keys())}."
                )
            # We don't use .loss here since the model may return tuples instead of ModelOutput.
            loss = outputs["loss"] if isinstance(outputs, dict) else outputs[0]

        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

The terminal shows:

```
(qwen) seamoon@gpu07:~/code/Qwen$ bash finetune/finetune_ds.sh 
[2024-01-06 17:55:53,192] torch.distributed.run: [WARNING] 
[2024-01-06 17:55:53,192] torch.distributed.run: [WARNING] *****************************************
[2024-01-06 17:55:53,192] torch.distributed.run: [WARNING] Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed. 
[2024-01-06 17:55:53,192] torch.distributed.run: [WARNING] *****************************************
[2024-01-06 17:55:54,784] [INFO] [real_accelerator.py:161:get_accelerator] Setting ds_accelerator to cuda (auto detect)
[2024-01-06 17:55:54,853] [INFO] [real_accelerator.py:161:get_accelerator] Setting ds_accelerator to cuda (auto detect)
The model is automatically converting to bf16 for faster inference. If you want to disable the automatic precision, please manually add bf16/fp16/fp32=True to "AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained".
Try importing flash-attention for faster inference...
Warning: import flash_attn rotary fail, please install FlashAttention rotary to get higher efficiency https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention/tree/main/csrc/rotary
Warning: import flash_attn rms_norm fail, please install FlashAttention layer_norm to get higher efficiency https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention/tree/main/csrc/layer_norm
Warning: import flash_attn fail, please install FlashAttention to get higher efficiency https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention
The model is automatically converting to bf16 for faster inference. If you want to disable the automatic precision, please manually add bf16/fp16/fp32=True to "AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained".
Try importing flash-attention for faster inference...
Warning: import flash_attn rotary fail, please install FlashAttention rotary to get higher efficiency https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention/tree/main/csrc/rotary
Warning: import flash_attn rms_norm fail, please install FlashAttention layer_norm to get higher efficiency https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention/tree/main/csrc/layer_norm
Warning: import flash_attn fail, please install FlashAttention to get higher efficiency https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00,  2.41it/s]
Loading data...
Formatting inputs...Skip in lazy mode
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:01<00:00,  1.10it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                                                                                   | 0/20 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/home/seamoon/anaconda3/envs/qwen/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py:429: UserWarning: torch.utils.checkpoint: please pass in use_reentrant=True or use_reentrant=False explicitly. The default value of use_reentrant will be updated to be False in the future. To maintain current behavior, pass use_reentrant=True. It is recommended that you use use_reentrant=False. Refer to docs for more details on the differences between the two variants.
  warnings.warn(
/home/seamoon/anaconda3/envs/qwen/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py:429: UserWarning: torch.utils.checkpoint: please pass in use_reentrant=True or use_reentrant=False explicitly. The default value of use_reentrant will be updated to be False in the future. To maintain current behavior, pass use_reentrant=True. It is recommended that you use use_reentrant=False. Refer to docs for more details on the differences between the two variants.
  warnings.warn(
{'loss': 1.1746, 'learning_rate': 1e-05, 'epoch': 0.24}                                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 1.2259, 'learning_rate': 9.931806517013612e-06, 'epoch': 0.48}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1804, 'learning_rate': 9.729086208503174e-06, 'epoch': 0.73}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1697, 'learning_rate': 9.397368756032445e-06, 'epoch': 0.97}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1526, 'learning_rate': 8.94570254698197e-06, 'epoch': 1.21}                                                                                                                         
{'loss': 0.1521, 'learning_rate': 8.386407858128707e-06, 'epoch': 1.45}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1554, 'learning_rate': 7.734740790612137e-06, 'epoch': 1.7}                                                                                                                         
{'loss': 0.1513, 'learning_rate': 7.008477123264849e-06, 'epoch': 1.94}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1523, 'learning_rate': 6.227427435703997e-06, 'epoch': 2.18}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1326, 'learning_rate': 5.412896727361663e-06, 'epoch': 2.42}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1484, 'learning_rate': 4.587103272638339e-06, 'epoch': 2.67}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1335, 'learning_rate': 3.7725725642960047e-06, 'epoch': 2.91}                                                                                                                       
{'loss': 0.1443, 'learning_rate': 2.991522876735154e-06, 'epoch': 3.15}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.133, 'learning_rate': 2.265259209387867e-06, 'epoch': 3.39}                                                                                                                         
{'loss': 0.1391, 'learning_rate': 1.6135921418712959e-06, 'epoch': 3.64}                                                                                                                       
{'loss': 0.1299, 'learning_rate': 1.0542974530180327e-06, 'epoch': 3.88}                                                                                                                       
{'loss': 0.1414, 'learning_rate': 6.026312439675553e-07, 'epoch': 4.12}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1366, 'learning_rate': 2.7091379149682683e-07, 'epoch': 4.36}                                                                                                                       
{'loss': 0.1349, 'learning_rate': 6.819348298638839e-08, 'epoch': 4.61}                                                                                                                        
{'loss': 0.1322, 'learning_rate': 0.0, 'epoch': 4.85}                                                                                                                                          
{'train_runtime': 99.7731, 'train_samples_per_second': 6.615, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.2, 'train_loss': 0.2510054260492325, 'epoch': 4.85}                                                  
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [01:39<00:00,  4.98s/it]
```

`Trainer.py` path: /home/seamoon/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py

[Check `finetune_ds.sh` from here](https://github.com/QwenLM/Qwen/blob/main/finetune/finetune_ds.sh)

[Check `finetune.py` from here](https://github.com/QwenLM/Qwen/blob/main/finetune.py)

My question is, is there any way of printing out the value of `labels`?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you provide informations about the main file ? and the path of the `trainer.py`?

Comment: Hi حمزة نبيل, I've updated the related files and paths in the question body~ Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: Try to raise error to check if the file you modifying is what used ?
`raise ValueError("Yes that the code !")`

Are you using any virtual env ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried raising error, and it didn't work (I'm using virtual env)

Comment: Well, you changed the wrong file , as the packages   for the env are under `anaconda3/envs/{env_name}/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `Trainer` and override `compute_loss`:

```py
from transformers import Trainer

class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        # get the labels
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        print(labels) # you can use loging
        # call the original compute_loss method
        return super().compute_loss(model, inputs, return_outputs=return_outputs)
```

Then you can create `trainer` using:

```py
    # Start trainner
    trainer = CustomTrainer(
        model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, args=training_args, **data_module
    )
```